# How can I add columns to custom post tables

Tags: custom-post-types, columns

I have created a custom post type. I also have added a meta box to my custom post type. What I want to do now is add my meta box as columns to my custom post table.

*My Custom Post*

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
// Create my custom post
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'spark_stars', 
        array('labels' => 
            array(
                'name' => __( 'Stars' ),
           'singular_name' => __( 'Star' )),
           'public' => true,
           'has_archive' => true,
           'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
        )
    );
 }

add_action('add_meta_boxes','stars_meta_box');
// Create my meta box
function stars_meta_box(){
    global $post;
    add_meta_box('first_name_meta_box','First Name',
        'first_name_meta_box_html','spark_stars','normal','default');
}
// Create meta box html
function first_name_meta_box_html(){
    wp_nonce_field('first_name','first_name_meta_box_nonce');
    $value = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'first_name_meta_box_key', true ); ?>
    <label>First Name: </label>
        <input type="text" name="fname" 
            value="<?php echo esc_attr($value); ?>"/>
<?php { 

add_action('manage_spark_stars_posts_columns',.....) // is this the function?
add_filter('manage_spark_stars_posts_columns',.....) // is this the function?
```

How can I get this meta box as a column in my custom post table and also how can I get the thumbnail of each post as a column in my custom post table?

Comment: By "meta box as a column", you mean adding the meta value into a table cell in the WP List Table?

Comment: Yes. The title of the meta box will be the name of the column and its value will be the content.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the [`manage_{$post_type}_posts_columns`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/manage_$post_type_posts_columns) filter is what you're looking for. You can then use the [`manage_posts_custom_column`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_posts_custom_column) action to manage the content for each column in the posts list view.

EDIT::

To add custom columns to your custom post type, you need to filter the columns being output using the [`manage_{$post_type}_posts_columns`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/manage_$post_type_posts_columns) where `$post_type` is the name you used to register the custom post type. In your case it would be `spark_stars`.

The `$columns` variable is an array of the current columns. You can either add to it completely override it as necessary.

```
add_filter('manage_spark_stars_posts_columns','filter_cpt_columns');

function filter_cpt_columns( $columns ) {
    // this will add the column to the end of the array
    $columns['first_name'] = 'First Name';
    //add more columns as needed

    // as with all filters, we need to return the passed content/variable
    return $columns;
}
```

The next step is to tell WordPress what content needs to be displayed in the column.
This can be done with the [`manage_posts_custom_column`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_posts_custom_column) action. The method below outputs the `First Name` if the post meta exists or a default string if not.

```
add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column','action_custom_columns_content', 10, 2 );
function action_custom_columns_content ( $column_id, $post_id ) {
    //run a switch statement for all of the custom columns created
    switch( $column_id ) { 
        case 'first_name':
            echo ($value = get_post_meta($post_id, 'first_name_meta_box_key', true ) ) ? $value : 'No First Name Given';
        break;

        //add more items here as needed, just make sure to use the column_id in the filter for each new item.

   }
}
```

Hopefully this is more clear!

Comment: Answers should be [more than plain links](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). They should actually be an answer instead of a route where someone will _maybe find_ an answer. Please help preventing link rot, [edit] your answer and provide the needed information that helps the OP as well as later visitors to solve their problem. Maybe add an example on how to use the filter - in context of the question.

Comment: I can't believe WordPress is coded this poorly.  Adding a column to the list of a custom post type in the admin should be a matter of registering that column in the custom post type's admin object, not calling some random global functions.

Comment: @kloddant I'm not sure what you're referring to. There is no random global function. Hooks are the paradigm that WordPress uses to allow customization. Are you referring to `add_action` and `add_filter`?